# Añadir scripts al DOM desde JS

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando hacer una aplicación para cargar cookies de forma selectiva a mi página. La idea el script es que yo cree una variable que contenga el código que quiero cagar por ejemplo:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX-2');
</script>
```

y luego añadirlo al DOM utilizando

```js
document.body.innerHTML += variable_con_la_cookie;
```

mi problema es que cuando voy a guardar el valor en la variable no me deja y me salta el error 'Unterminated template literal'

Código en el cual guardo la variable:

```
            var variable_con_la_cookie = 
            `<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
            <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX-2">     </script>
            <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX-2');
            </script>`;
```

¿Coneceis alguna manera efectiva de poder añadir cualquier código desde JS sin tener que utilizar el createElement?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres evitar usar createElement? Es la forma habitual de hacerlo

Comment: La idea sería añadir una variable por cada cookie que se quiera añadir, por ejemplo para Google Analytics tendrá un bloque para insertar todo, para Hotjar otro para LinkedIn etc.. Y para añadir esos elementos de primeras lo voy hacer a mano desde código pero en un futuro no muy lejano será por una interfaz gráfica en la cual tu metes ese bloque entero... Espero haberme explicado